# SQL - Select the latest dated 'child' record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am looking for a SQL query to find a parent record value and the *latest* datetime value from its multiple child records. I envisage the solution using  SELECT TOP 1 in a join clause, but I'm a bit stumped on how to do it.

The following is a simplified version. I've looked for help for this, but because the parent and child records are sort of stored in the same table, but using another table to link them, I've struggled to find the answer to my question.

I have a *[Case]* table that stores data for two types of real-life event: a **referral** and a **visit**.

**One referral** is linked to **many visits**.

The data that 'links' them together is stored in a table called *EventCaseAutoCreate*

```
Case table (Referrals and Visits)
------------------------
CaseNo uniqueidentifier,
ActiveDate datetime,
CaseType varchar       (Visit or Referral)


EventCaseAutoCreate table
------------------------
EventCaseAutoCreateRef uniqueidentifier,
CaseNo               (Visit [case] table caseref value)
OriginalCaseNo       (Referral [case] table caseref value)
```

So because the Case table contains both Referral and Visit rows, [case].activedate is either the 'Referral Date' or the 'Visit Date' depending on CaseType.

So you'd have the following:

```
Case
CaseNo    ActiveDate    CaseType
10000     01/07/2014    Referral
10001     02/07/2014    Visit
10005     05/07/2014    Referral
10002     07/07/2014    Visit
10003     08/07/2014    Visit
10004     20/07/2014    Visit
10006     06/07/2014    Visit
```

and

```
EventCaseAutoCreate
EventCaseAutoCreateRef    CaseNo    OriginalCaseNo
GUID                      10001     10000
GUID                      10002     10000
GUID                      10003     10000   
GUID                      10004     10000
GUID                      10006     10005
```

I'd like to know the query to achieve the following results:

```
ReferralCaseNo    ReferralDate    LatestVisitDate
10000             01/07/2014      20/07/2014
10005             05/07/2014      06/07/2014
```

I am using SQL Server 2005. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my stab at it:

```
select a.caseno as ReferralCaseNo, c1.ActiveDate as ReferralDate, b.maxdate as LatestVisitDate 
from cases c1 inner join 
(
   select distinct e.originalcaseno as caseno
   from cases c inner join events e on c.caseno = e.caseno
)a on c1.caseno = a.caseno
inner join 
(
   select max(ActiveDate) as maxdate, e2.originalcaseno
   from cases c2 inner join events e2
     on c2.caseno = e2.caseno
   group by e2.originalcaseno
 ) b on a.caseno = b.originalcaseno
```

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31c29/15)

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like it's working. 

I had to change the events join to c.caseno = e.ORIGINALcaseno, in table a. 

Can you talk me through why you did what you did, if you have the time? Just so I know that I understand what you did?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to look up the original case number in the `EventCaseAuteCreate` table and then do conditional aggregation:

```
select OriginalCaseNo as ReferralCaseNo,
       min(case when casetype = 'Referral' then ActiveDate end) as ReferralDate,
       max(case when casetype = 'Visit' then ActiveDate end) as LatestVisitDate
from cases c join
     EventCaseAutoCreate eac
     on c.caseno = eac.caseno or
        c.caseno = eac.OriginalCaseNo
group by eac.OriginalCaseNo;
```

Comment: @MilenPavlov . . . Your SQL Fiddle (which I commend ;) misspells "Referral".

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, I'm going to try yours now too :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work. I get the nulls. It could be down to a problem in how I've phrased my question.

Comment: @MilenPavlov . . . My apologies.  I totally missed that the referral has the original case number, so it was producing `NULL` values.  The fixed the answer, because it should at least be correct.